# FETCH JS: ¿Por que recibo TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

No se donde está el problema. Al poner el fetch en una FUNCION me arroja el error **TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource** pero si lo pongo por fuera se ejecuta correctamente. ¿porque sucede esto? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Dejo el código para que vean el problema. Gracias!

```
let buttonSearch;
let inputPokemon;
let namePokemon;

//Este codigo funciona...
fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((pokemon) => {
        console.log(pokemon.name);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })


function reload() {
    document.getElementById('searchPokemon').addEventListener('click', searchPokemon);
    inputPokemon = document.querySelector('form .input-pokemon').value.toLowerCase();
    namePokemon = document.querySelector('.name-pokemon');
}

function searchPokemon() {
    reload();
    console.log(inputPokemon);
    //Este codigo dentro de una funcion NO FUNCIONA
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/pikachu`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((pokemon) => {
            console.log(pokemon.name);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

reload();
```

El objetivo FINAL es que cuando se presione #searchPokemon me traiga por FETCH el JSON de ese pokemon. Para este ejemplo y para que me entiendan he puesto directamente PIKACHU para que vean el error que me arroja cuando esta dentro de una funcion, por fuera funciona correctamente.

gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Al menos en el ejemplo tienes una recursividad. En la función reload llamas a la función searchPokemon y en esta última llamas a función reload, lo que hace que se cree un loop infinito por lo que pudiera ser ese el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema. Al no estar el e.preventDefault(); el form se enviaba y recargaba. Por lo cual el fetch no llegaba a realizarse y era lo que generaba el error. Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve.

Comment: de que forma haces alusión? deberías colocar todo tu código ya que respondiste que te faltaba algo en tu forma pero en la pregunta no existe un form

Comment: @vicasas agrega la siguiente linea de código handler de tu onClick o onSubmit:
`if (e && "preventDefault" in e) e.preventDefault()` siendo `e` el primer argumento de tu handler. Para los que utilizan typescript, pueden usar la siguiente interfaz: `React.SyntheticEvent`. @ZeR0ByTe deberías marcas esta respuesta como la correcta.